# NestJS Fastify graphql e2e test failures

Tags: graphql, nestjs, apollo-server, fastify

I have a simple NestJS + Fastify + Graphql app, however when I try to use fastify in my e2e, the tests are erring out. I can't seem to figure out the issue here. Anybody else seen this? When I run the app, everything works as expected.

**Depedencies from package.json**
For those who know the dependencies better than I. Perhaps there is a mismatch.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^0.5.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/graphql": "^7.6.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-fastify": "^7.2.0",
    "apollo-server-fastify": "^2.16.1",
    "class-transformer": "^0.3.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.12.2",
    "graphql": "^15.3.0",
    "joi": "^17.2.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "type-graphql": "^1.0.0-rc.3",
    "typegraphql-nestjs": "^0.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.3",
    "@types/humps": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "25.2.3",
    "@types/joi": "^14.3.4",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^13.9.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "3.0.2",
    "eslint": "7.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^5.0.3",
    "humps": "^2.0.1",
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "jest": "26.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lint-staged": "^10.2.11",
    "mockserver-client": "^5.11.1",
    "organize-imports-cli": "^0.7.0",
    "prettier": "1.19.1",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "26.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "ts-node": "^8.6.2",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4"
  },
```

**Code**

```js
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { AppModule } from './../src/app.module';
import {
  FastifyAdapter,
  NestFastifyApplication,
} from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';

describe('AppController (e2e)', () => {
  let app: NestFastifyApplication;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication<NestFastifyApplication>(
      new FastifyAdapter(),
    );

    await app.init();
  });

  it('GET /', () => {
    console.log('HELLO');
    return app.inject({
      method: 'get',
      url: '/',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
  });
});
```

**Output**

```sh
  AppController (e2e)
    ✕ GET / (399 ms)

  ● AppController (e2e) › GET /

    TypeError: The "warning" argument must be one of type Error or string. Received type objectTypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "warning" argument must be one of type Error or string. Received type object

      at emitWarning (../node_modules/fastify/lib/warnings.js:63:11)
      at new Parser (../node_modules/fastify/lib/contentTypeParser.js:233:5)
      at ContentTypeParser.add (../node_modules/fastify/lib/contentTypeParser.js:51:18)
      at Object.addContentTypeParser (../node_modules/fastify/lib/contentTypeParser.js:262:30)
      at ApolloServer.<anonymous> (../node_modules/apollo-server-fastify/src/ApolloServer.ts:168:22)
      at ../node_modules/apollo-server-fastify/dist/ApolloServer.js:8:71
      at __awaiter (../node_modules/apollo-server-fastify/dist/ApolloServer.js:4:12)

  console.log
    HELLO

      at Object.<anonymous> (app.e2e-spec.ts:24:13)
```

Comment: could you add your package.json?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon added

Comment: Few thoughts: 1.) Ensure on most recent version of fastify (`@nestjs/platform-fastify@7.4.3`); 2.) Remove `@nestjs/platform-express` as a dependency (can possibly created confusion). If none of those work then can you: 1.) confirm that your [GET] / route is simply the default (i.e. return string `hello world`). 2.) If there is any graphql stuff in that route (or if it is different from boilerplate) then could you please post the full controller + any applicable services?